# Reading and Unmarshalling API results in Golang

Tags: go, struct

In the below program I'm extracting some data from an API.

It outputs a rather complex data.
When I `ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)`, the result is of type `[]uint8`.
If I try to read the results, its just a random array of integers.

However, I'm able to read it if I convert it to string using `string(diskinfo)`
But I want to use this in a Struct and having trouble unmarshalling.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "reflect"
)

type ApiResults struct {
    results []struct {
        statement_id int `json.statement_id`
        series       []struct {
            name string `json.name`
            tags struct {
                host string `json.host`
            }
            columns []string      `json.columns`
            values  []interface{} `json.values`
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    my_url := "my_url"
    my_qry := fmt.Sprintf("my_query")

    resp, err := http.Get(my_url + url.QueryEscape(my_qry))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ERROR:  %v\n", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(resp))
        diskinfo, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf((diskinfo)))
        fmt.Println(diskinfo)
        fmt.Println(string(diskinfo))
        diskinfo_string := string(diskinfo)
        data := ApiResults{}
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(diskinfo_string), &data)
        //fmt.Printf("Values = %v\n", data.results.series.values)
        //fmt.Printf("Server = %v\n", data.results.series.tags.host)
    }
}
```

If I view the data as a string, I get this (formatted):

```
{"results":[
  {"statement_id":0,
   "series":[
    {"name":"disk",
     "tags":{"host":"myServer1"},
     "columns":["time","disk_size"],
     "values":[["2021-07-07T07:53:32.291490387Z",1044]]},
    {"name":"disk",
     "tags":{"host":"myServer2"},
     "columns":["time","disk_size"],
     "values":[["2021-07-07T07:53:32.291490387Z",1046]]}
  ]}
]}
```

I think my `Apireturn` struct is also structured incorrectly because the API results have info for multiple hosts.
But first, I doubt if the data has to be sent in a different format to the struct. Once I do this, I can probably try to figure out how to read from the Struct next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ioutil.ReadAll` already provides you the data in the type `byte[]`. Therefore you can just call `json.Unmarshal` passing it as a parameter.

```golang
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)


func toStruct(res *http.Response) (*ApiResults, error) {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()

    data := ApiResults{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &data); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return data, nil 
}
```

There also seems to be an issue with your struct. The correct way to use struct tags is as follows. Plus, fields need to be exported for the json tag (used by `json.Umarshal`) to work – starting with uppercase will do it.

```golang
type ApiResults struct {
    Results []struct {
        StatementId int `json:"statement_id"`
        Series       []struct {
            Name string `json:"name"`
            Tags struct {
                Host string `json:"host"`
            } `json:"tags"`
            Columns []string      `json:"columns"`
            Values  []interface{} `json:"values"`
        } `json:"series"`
    } `json:"results"`
}
```